# How to write more than one condition in ternary operator in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ternary-operator

My Picture:

[image]

In this picture i am saving group type using radio button.if balance sheet is selected it saved as "B" and profit and loss as "P".if without select anything,it save as "T".

Now my problem is i am using ternary operator to check conditions,but for me only 2nd conditions is working.It is not working for more than one conditions in that operator.
How i resolve my problem.

```
public function GEntry()
{

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gName', 'gName', 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">',
            '</div>');
        $check1 = isset($_POST['gType']);

        $check =  ($check1 == 'B') ? "B"  : ($check1 == 'P') ? "P" :'T';
    //$check1 = isset($_POST['tin_no1']) ? "Y" : "N";

        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            $data= array(
                'gName' => $this->input->post('gName'),
                'gType' => $check
                );
        //means insert a data into the table
            $this->db->insert('groups',$data);

            return redirect('Master/Groups');
        }
```

Comment: Nesting multiple ternary operators is a big code smell. It quickly becomes unreadable and can be very hard to maintain. I would recommend doing it in multiple steps instead. You should always try to write your code as readable as possible.

Comment: What has this question to do with Codeigniter? `$check = in_array($check1, ['B', 'P']) ? $check1 : 'T'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the post data to the variable `$check1`. You are checking like this `$check1 = isset($_POST['gType']);` this will give you `true` / `false`.

Update like below:

`$check1 = isset($_POST['gType']) && in_array($_POST['gType'], ['B', 'P']) ? $_POST['gType'] : 'T';`

Then remove this line `$check =  ($check1 == 'B') ? "B"  : ($check1 == 'P') ? "P" :'T';`

Answer (score 0):

You can capture an entire ternary operator with using brackets like this:

```
$a = ($b === 'A') ? 'A' : (($b === 'B') ? 'B' : (($b === 'C') ? 'C' : 'D'));
```

**BUT** ... i would not recommend you this procedure, if your decisioning takes more than 2-3 conditions. In that case, i would recommend you, to use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead:

```
switch ($b)
{
    case 'A':
        $a = 'A';
        break;
    default:
        $a = 'D';
        break;
}
```

**ALSO** ... i would recommend you to use a `===` comparator instead of the `==` comparator like in the code provided by you. The third `=` makes sure, that both of the given values are of the same data type, so you compare a `string` with another `string` in your example.